# git filter-branch not working when project includes other submodules

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

Suppose I have the following project structure:

```
.git

--APP
-----F

--LIBS
------A
-------.git
------B
-------.git
------C
-------.git
------D
-------.git
```

`F` is a sub-folder under the APP folder.
`A, B, C` and `D` are four submodules located under the LIBS folder.

What I want to do is to extract the `F` folder to a different repository(currently it is just a simple sub-folder).

So far, I have done the following:

```
for remote in `git branch -r | grep -v /HEAD`; do git checkout --track $remote; done
```

after that, I ran:

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat --subdirectory-filter APP/F/ -- --all
```

The result is:

```
.git

--F

--LIBS
------A
-------.git
------B
-------.git
------C
-------.git
------D
-------.git
```

seems like the sub-modules in the hierarchy still rewritten history.

but, the result I wanted is to remain only with the F directory, without the other submodules..:

```
--F
---.git
```

Comment: what's the error message? Please share

Comment: @rajibkarmaker there is not error message...

Comment: Are the old submodules actually *tracked* by git, or just hanging out in the filesystem?

Comment: What @o11c said.  Do `git ls-files LIBS`.  Nobody's ever taught Git how to handle part-time submodules, it's a corner-case-ucopia.  For instance, I don't see where you told your filter-branch to remove the `.gitmodules` entries.  `git submodule` is a toolbag  to help wrangle nested repositories.

Comment: You seem to have answer, could you clarify what is still unclear?

Answer (score 0):

`filter-branch` is not the correct tool to work with submodules. What you want is to remove the respective submodules (with rm) and **then** using filter-branch to move the hierarchy root like so:

```
rm -r LIBS && git add --all && git commit -m "Dropped submodules"
git filter-branch --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat --subdirectory-filter APP/F/
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried it, I think the result is better now, but not as expected. All the submodules were removed from the folder but after the two lines u've suggested, I still have all the commits that are related to the removed submodules in the git tree(and I want to remove them from there!). Any more suggestions?

Comment: @ranifisch could you elaborate?

Comment: I ran the two lines you have suggested, and the result is that I have all the content of the APP/F in the main directory, meaning:

.git

--F

but when I opened it in the gitExtensions/SourceTree GUI Tool, I looked through the git tree history and I see commits related to the following submodules! :
LIBS/A
LIBS/B
LIBS/C
LIBS/D

Comment: That means you want to also delete the history that these directories ever had... that's a separate filter-branch invocation, IIUC

Comment: No.. that's not what I want, I want the Submodules history to remain, maybe what I need is to remove the reference to these submodules in the tree history? IDK

Comment: What you need is to become clear about what you want to achieve. I'm really not following because what you tell me seems self-contradictory...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179541/discussion-between-ranifisch-and-vogel612).